# Does it support executing only selected scenario based on tag from called feature file?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, karate, cucumber-junit

Would like to understand if possible to execute only selected scenarios within a called feature file either based on tag or scenario name. i.e Say Have two feature files file 1.feature and file2.feature with 10 scenarios in each. Would like to run one of the scenario from file 1.feature in the file 2.feature.

As per the Karate framework user guide, supports only calling the entire feature file inside another. it would be great if its allows to executed selected scenarios from the called feature file. Let me know if any alternate approach to achieve this.

Usage example: Have feature file which covers workflows of checking existence of branch and directories in GIT. We need to use some of the scenarios from this file in other to check creation or removal of branches and directories on performing some workflows in the application.

Thanks & regards,
Basava Kumar M

Comment: see duplicate q & a. if you need anything more, please contribute code